# Prove that for every two subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am very lost in this, can anyone explain this to me please?

Let $U = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$, and $f$ be a function from $U$ into $U$. Finally, let
$F : P(U) → P(U)$ be the function defined by $F(X) = \{f(x)\> |\> x \in X\}$
For instance, if $f(x) = 13 − x$, and $X = \{1,3,4,7\}$, then $F(X) = \{f(1),f(3),f(4),f(7)\} = \{12, 10, 9, 6\}$.

a. Prove that for every two subsets $A$, $B$ of $U$, we have $F(A ∩ B) \subseteq F(A) ∩ F(B)$.

b. Give an example that shows that $F(A- B)$ is not necessarily a subset of $F(A)- F(B)$.

Comment: Try to work on the elements of $F(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic approach.** For (a), if some element $y \in F(A \cap B)$, then there must exist $x \in A \cap B$ such that $f(x) = y$.  Now if $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ *and* $x \in B$.  What does that tell us about $y$ with respect to $F(A)$ and $F(B)$?

For (b), it is easiest to construct a specific counterexample that has $F(A-B) \not\subseteq F(A)-F(B)$.  One way is to find some function $f$ and subsets $A$ and $B$ that are not equal, and yet $F(A) = F(B)$.  Think especially of functions that are not one-to-one.

Comment: It is the basic approach for both parts.  Math SE is not a homework-answering service.  Complete answers do happen, but they're much more likely when a student shows some effort beyond copying and pasting.  In that case, the answer becomes a matter of finishing what the student started.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it's assigned homework or not; I shouldn't have misled you in that regard.  What I've provided is most of the proof.  If you've read it carefully and properly understand it, the completion is practically fill-in-the-blank.